Why are my apps closing randomly?
Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 22.04. After I installed Ubuntu I installed a few apps like Whatsapp, IDLE, etc. Since then I checked for updates, concluded no updates or upgrades. After that whatever the app I had open it is closing repeatedly with every opening with random timing. I tried to open Firefox, but it does not open. When I try to open Firefox a window suddenly appears and disappears. For some random time the keyboard is also not working. Sometimes while switching tabs Firefox suddenly terminates. By default VSCode opens Firefox when npm starts, but it is not working.

I've seen this problem before on a computer with both integrated graphics from the CPU and a discrete graphics card. Ubuntu kept switching back and forth between the integrated graphics and the discrete graphics.
